# extracting number of items in date range for each row in huge data frame in R

Tags: r, date, vectorization

I was wondering if anyone had some suggestions for efficient function to be applied to a big data frame (2m rows, 50 variables) to pull out number of items that lie within a date range specified in the row. For example my data frame looks something like this:

```
row.name   start_time          end_time              jid     hostname
1930525    2016-01-21 15:41:35 2016-01-21 15:47:40   1976235 hpc1node10
1930526    2016-01-21 15:40:50 2016-01-21 15:47:44   1976230 hpc1node08
1930527    2016-01-21 15:37:20 2016-01-21 15:47:46   1976192 hpc1node16
1930528    2016-01-21 15:43:05 2016-01-21 15:47:53   1976533 hpc1node13
1930529    2016-01-21 15:37:35 2016-01-21 15:47:54   1976197 hpc1node16
```

I want to count for each row (job) how many other jobs have been running at the same time. So which jobs finished in between `start_time` and `end_time` and jobs started in between `start_time` and `end_time`.

I tried coming up with a function to use with `by`, but it's woefully slow. Yet I can't think of a better way. My stab:

```
get_range <- function(r, d=NULL) {

  # Attempt at reducing the number of items by only 
  #   looking at 500 either side for the same hostname
  dd = subset(d, jobnumber>r$jobnumber-500&jobnumber<r$jobnumber+500&hostname==r$hostname)

  running_jobs = sum( 
    (dd$end_time>=r$start_time & dd$end_time <= r$end_time) | 
    (dd$start_time >= r$start_time & dd$start_time <= r$end_time)
    )

  running_jobs
}
```

then running

```
by(d, get_range, d=d)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your example, all entries are overlapping each others... hard to test with this. A wrokable input along with expected output could be great. Maybe you can have a look at `foverlaps` in package data.table.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this efficiently using the `foverlaps` function from the *data.table* package which is specifically designed for large datasets:

```
library(data.table)
# converting to a 'data.table'
# and setting the keys to the time columns
# and adding an index column
setDT(d, key = c("hostname","start_time","end_time"))[, xid := .I]
# checking for overlaps & counting the number of overlaps
tmp <- foverlaps(d, d, which = TRUE)[, .N-1, xid]
# adding the count (N := V1) to 'd' by joining with 'tmp' on 'xid'
d[tmp, N := V1, on="xid"][, xid := NULL]
```

which gives:

```
> d
   row.name          start_time            end_time     jid   hostname N
1:  1930526 2016-01-21 15:40:50 2016-01-21 15:47:44 1976230 hpc1node08 0
2:  1930525 2016-01-21 15:41:35 2016-01-21 15:47:40 1976235 hpc1node10 0
3:  1930528 2016-01-21 15:43:05 2016-01-21 15:47:53 1976533 hpc1node13 0
4:  1930527 2016-01-21 15:37:20 2016-01-21 15:47:46 1976192 hpc1node16 1
5:  1930529 2016-01-21 15:37:35 2016-01-21 15:47:54 1976197 hpc1node16 1
```

In the above solution I have used `type = "any"` (this is not in the code above because this is the default) to look for other rows that have a `start_time` and `end_time` that overlap with the `start_time` and `end_time` of other rows within the `hostname` groups. Other possible values for `type` are: `within`, `start` & `end`.

Furthermore, I used `.N-1` to take account for 'self'-overlaps.

Comment: ```foverlaps``` sounds really nice, but I just ran out of memory doing 100,000 rows. Also, I needed to take hostname into account, and in this example, only jobs overlapping are on node16. So only there N should be 1, everywhere else 0.